# Efficiently send a stream of UDP packets

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, udp

I know how to open an UDP socket in C++, and I also know how to send packets through that. When I send a packet I correctly receive it on the other end, and everything works fine.

**EDIT**: I also built a fully working acknowledgement system: packets are numbered, checksummed and acknowledged, so at any time I know how many of the packets that I sent, say, during the last second were actually received from the other endpoint. Now, the data I am sending will be readable only when ALL the packets are received, so that I really don't care about packet ordering: I just need them all to arrive, so that they could arrive in random sequences and it still would be ok since having them sequentially ordered would still be useless.

Now, I have to transfer a big big chunk of data (say 1 GB) and I'd need it to be transferred as fast as possible. So I split the data in say 512 bytes chunks and send them through the UDP socket.

Now, since UDP is connectionless it obviously doesn't provide any speed or transfer efficiency diagnostics. So if I just try to send a ton of packets through my socket, my socket will just accept them, then they will be sent all at once, and my router will send the first couple and then start dropping them. So this is NOT the most efficient way to get this done.

What I did then was making a cycle:

- Sleep for a while
- Send a bunch of packets
- Sleep again and so on

I tried to do some calibration and I achieved pretty good transfer rates, however I have a thread that is continuously sending packets in small bunches, but I have nothing but an experimental idea on what the interval should be and what the size of the bunch should be. In principle, I can imagine that sleeping for a really small amount of time, then sending just one packet at a time would be the best solution for the router, however it is completely unfeasible in terms of CPU performance (I probably would need to busy wait since the time between two consecutive packets would be really small).

So is there any other solution? Any widely accepted solution? I assume that my router has a buffer or something like that, so that it can accept SOME packets all at once, and then it needs some time to process them. How big is that buffer?

I am not an expert in this so any explanation would be great.

Please note, however, that for technical reasons there is *no way at all* I can use TCP.

Comment: start playing with [iperf](https://iperf.fr/). see how far you are from the speed that you can get with iperf. It is open source so you can see what they've done.

Comment: Hmm.. maybe you need some kind of flow-control protocol.  You could base it on ACK messages returned by the peer, so that the datagram send rate could be reduced if the overall losses exceeded some value.  Such small,512 byte, datagrams does not seem very efficient:(

Comment: Have you thought about making your socket `SOCK_SEQPACKET`?

Comment: @MartinJames I also thought about doing something like that! I thought that I could do a fixed time step (say, 0.01 seconds) and then have a variable number of packets that get sent at each step. But I am not sure on how to determine what is the best step!

Comment: @Freddy is that based on UDP as well? It is fundamental to me that I use UDP, and I really don't care at all about packet ordering.

Comment: @MartinJames what could be an optimal size for my packets? I was worried about the MTU issue...

Comment: If you can't use TCP, you could still read about how TCP's flow-control features work, and perhaps get some ideas from that about how to do something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in some other comments, what you're describing is a flow control system. The wikipedia article has a good overview of various ways of doing this:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_control_%28data%29

The solution that you have in place (sleeping for a hard-coded period between packet groups) will work in principle, but in order to get reasonable performance in a real-world system you need to be able to react to changes in the network. This means implementing some kind of feedback where you automatically adjust both the outgoing data rate and packet size in response to to network characteristics, such as throughput and packetloss.

One simple way of doing this is to use the number of re-transmitted packets as an input into your flow control system. The basic idea would be that when you have a lot of re-transmitted packets, you would reduce the packet size, reduce the data rate, or both. If you have very few re-transmitted packets, you would increase packet size & data rate until you see an increase in re-transmitted packets.

That's something of a gross oversimplification, but I think you get the idea.

Comment: Good! Actually, I have already done such a thing. The packets I send are checksummed, they get acknowledged, and I also have an idea on how many packets I sent during say the last half second were actually received by the other endpoint. Now, I thought about changing the number of packets I send each time a dispatch() function is called. But how frequently should I call it? Be K the number of times I call it every second, be D the number of packets I send each time i call it. Be N the number of packets per second, then N = K * D. But I suppose the efficiency also depends on D, right?

Comment: I mean, suppose that I want to send 1000 packets every second. I suppose that sleeping a second, sending 1000 packets, then sleeping a second is not the same thing as sleeping a millisecond, sending a packet, and then sleeping again. But for very high N, keeping D = 1 and increasing K gets unfeasible.

Comment: Moreover, I am not even sure that the very paradigm sleep - send - sleep - send is what I should use. Maybe there are pre-built solutions that I know nothing about?

Comment: Ah, okay. So you have reliable transport already, and you're looking for optimal efficiency. You might make that clear in the question.